# Mongodb extensions installing and loading but class not found

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7

I try install php7.0, after install I have trouble. My application use `MongoClient` class extensions `mongo` in `php5`, but this extensions is depricated I'm install `mongodb` and enable this extensions.

```
mongodb
mongodb support enabled
mongodb version     1.1.3
mongodb stability   stable
libmongoc version   1.3.3
libbson version     1.3.3
```

it's output my phpinfo. but `MongoClient` class not found

Answer (score 1):

Legacy driver (i.e. `mongo`) is not compatible with new driver (i.e. `mongodb`) - basically if you were using driver directly you need to rewrite all interactions with it.

Alternatively you can use library like [mongo-php-adapter](https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter) which provides old API atop new driver.